# Done button on UINavigation controller is not navigating back

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

when i click the done button nothing is happening where it is supposed to navigate back to mainviewcontroller

```
UIBarButtonItem * button = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                                          target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];


-(void)dismissView: (id)sender

{

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

It should navigate back to mainviewcontroller. But it is doing nothing. Any ideas what is wrong.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please add more information to get more context. How are you entering the controller you want to pop? Did you pushed it or is it a modal view controller? Did you connect your Done button to that method in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Was the current ViewController pushed onto the navigation stack?

`self.navigationController` only returns a navigation controller if the view controller is in its stack. This property is nil if a navigation controller cannot be found.

Debug and check its not nil. Put in some break points and see where the point of failure is. Is dismissView: even being called? What part of your code is `[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];` ?